# How does requirejs work with child pages?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I understand the concept of using requirejs to load specific modules in a particular order but how is it supposed to be used if child pages require other scripts, especially if they are extensive?

I don't get how you'd be able to use require js on child pages since you have already included the script tag on a master page which consequentially appears on the child page.

Comment: Master page? Child page? Isn't that some sort of ASP-specific includes system?

Comment: Yes. To clarify, I am referring a general template or layout that is used in the overall site and the content pages that use that template for formatting. The general layout can reference modules that will be necessary across many pages while a content page would have page specific modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the page already has the script loaded from the template, you would just use it by calling the `require()` function.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now. Doh, don't know how I missed that.